# AttributeError at /account/delete/testuser1: 'str' object has no attribute 'field'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to allow users to delete their own account but am faced with the error:

AttributeError at /account/delete/testuser1: 'str' object has no attribute 'field'

The user is not deleted too. Any idea why? I am trying to make it such that the delete button is in the account page and when i press delete, the user gets deleted and redirected back to the home page
Will be nice if you can share how i can create a function to deactivate an account too..is it simply setting is_active = False?

html

```
          <form action="{% url 'account:delete_account' username=request.user.username %}" method="GET">{% csrf_token %}
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteaccount ml-3" href="{% url 'account:delete_account' username=request.user.username %}">Delete Account</a> 
            </form>
```

views.py

```
def delete_user(request, username):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        try:
            user = Account.objects.get(username=username)
            user.delete()
            context['msg'] = 'Bye Bye'
        except Exception as e: 
            context['msg'] = 'Something went wrong!'
    else:
        context['msg'] = 'Request method should be "DELETE"!'
    return redirect(request, 'HomeFeed/snippets/home.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
 path('delete/<username>', delete_user, name='delete_account'),
```

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it simply by changing the view to this:
It worked but it seems too easy to be true. Could someone check to see if it works? Do I need things like request.method==delete etc?

```
def delete_user(request, username):
    context = {}

    user = Account.objects.get(username=username)
    logout(request)
    user.delete()
    return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
```